# java7 ws soap client error: handshake_failure

Tags: java, soap, client, ws

can any one help below error

While calling soap webservice  through wsimport tool generated client i am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:194)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:163)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getNewTransactions(Unknown Source)
        at com.ttk.business.webservice.haad.HaadClient.main(HaadClient.java:55)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:105)
        ... 14 more
```

debug mode

Comment: Java7?  Why so Old?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response ,that project is old project we are maintaining we con't change jre or jdk some dependencies are there like reports jars  etc ..